# spring.net and WCF Rest Service

Tags: wcf, rest, spring.net

I am building a WCF Rest Service using VS2010 .net 4.0 and the Rest service template.  I would like to introduce spring.net - IoC but I am not able to get spring initialized when the `InstanceContextMode.Single` is set.  For all other settings I can use `IInstanceProvider` interface and introduce a custom behaviour.

My question is:

Is there any other way I can get spring initialized?

Comment: Please read the note in 30.2.: http://springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/wcf.html
MSDN: If the InstanceContextMode of the service is Single, the system does not call the GetInstance or ReleaseInstance methods.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply Andreas, already aware of that.. 
I was wondering if there is another way of getting spring to work for all InstanceContextMode(s)?
I am looking at creating a custom ServiceHostFactory (replace WebServiceHostFactory in global.asax) and override the CreateServiceHost by providing a spring proxytype of the WCF rest service.

Comment: Imho you are looking for Spring.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory. https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-net/blob/master/src/Spring/Spring.Services/ServiceModel/Activation/WebServiceHostFactory.cs

Comment: I was looking at that but the problem is that the reference passed to create `ServiceHostBase` is the fully quilified type name of the WCF service, and when `if (applicationContext.ContainsObject(reference))` is called it returns false as the name doesnt match the config name...Is there a way of overriding this, or am i missing something.  Thanks for your reply

Comment: The simple solution is to use the fully qualified type name as your object name in your config, as Sebastian pointed out you can also add an alias to your spring config `<alias name="MyService" alias="Fully.Qualified.Service.Class"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just saw the comments in the main response

If your only problem is the name of the reference, you could create your own and fix the reference parameter, or add a dictionary where you set some aliases in the xml config and do a lookup against that.

---

As far as I know you can't use Spring when the InstanceContextMode is single; from the doc:

> While integrating 'natively' with WCF does seem to be the most natural
>   approach there is one 'gotya' that needs to be investigated further to
>   see if there is an acceptable workaround in order for this approach to
>   be viable. The issue is that if the service is configured to be a
>   singleton, for example using
>   [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)] then
>   the invocation of the IInstanceProvider is short-circuited.

The documentation suggests this:

> One workaround, which is not very appealing, is to use the PerCall instancing mode but set the
>   singleton attribute in the Spring configuration to true, this way the
>   same instance is always returned.

More info here: http://www.springframework.net/docs/1.2.0-M1/reference/html/wcf.html